# Specify where imported css will be injected in <head>

Tags: astrojs

As [documented](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#cascading-order), Astro injects the imported css after any static loaded `<link>` css.
How can I bypass this setting ? Is there any way to specify where the `import` will be loaded ?

Here's a [simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zb3zp3?file=src%2Flayouts%2FLayout.astro):

```
---
import '../style.css'
---

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="Astro description" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Test</title>

        <!-- I would like the 'import '../style.css' to be injected here.  -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static.css">

        <!-- But astro injects it here. -->

    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- A workaround, is to load the static.css here instead. -->

        <slot />
    </body>
</html>
```

---

PS. I understand that I could simply add `static.css` inside `src` folder and import it in order, but it's a project requirement that I do not touch `static.css` and load it last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `?url` import:

[?url CSS Imports](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#url-css-imports)

```html
---
import css from '../global.css?url'

import '../style.css'
---

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="Astro description" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href={css}>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static.css">
    </head>
</html>
```

If your stylesheet is smaller than 4kb it is possible for the `?url` import to return the content of the stylesheet instead of a url. To avoid this issue, make sure you have `vite.build.assetsInlineLimit: 0` set in your config

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
    vite: {
        build: {
            assetsInlineLimit: 0,
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: There's a big "IF", but I think that's the only way for now. Thanks !